# What happens to photons, electrons, etc

Tags: optics, photons, biophysics, vision

What happens to photons when they hit our eye? where do they end up? if they generate heat, why our eye don't get overheated?

Similarly what happens to electrons when the light hits certain metals, which causes "weakly connected" electrons to get hit out? 
Shouldn't then light constantly shining on a piece of metal eventually cause it to decay, and get split to electrons, and other particles?

(sorry if I'm not using right scientific terminology)

Comment: See [How do we see? Where do the photons disappear?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/202284/50583) and [In photo-electric experiment, if the light is exposed to a metal plate for a long enough interval, does the plate become lighter?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1716/50583)

Comment: Voting to close because of the answers given by the obvious google search: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=What+happens+to+photons+when+they+hit+our+eye&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=bByZVq6RIYrTUZjOjcAB which it seems to me was not used.

Comment: You have to distinct questions here, please post only *one* question per post.

Answer (score 3):

> **What happens to photons when they hit our eye?**

Some of them pass through the iris and are focussed by the lens onto the retina where they are absorbed by rods or cones.

> **where do they end up?**

Some of them end up absorbed by rods/cones, some by other tissues, some are reflected (c.f. red-eye in photography).

> **why our eye don't get overheated?**

It does if you stare at a bright source of light (sun, lasers, arc-welders etc). This causes permanent damage and irrevocable loss of sight (in at least part of the visual field)

The eye includes a mechanism for preventing too much light entering it. This is the iris. When this is overloaded, a secondary mechanism is activated, this is the eyelid.

Temperature in the body is regulated. The mechanisms have their limits. I believe blood flow is one way heat is transferred from place to place in the body.

> **Similarly what happens to electrons when the light hits certain metals**

They may get excited, temporarily. You should probably ask this as a separate question but the answer should be easily found by searching.

Comment: Very good answer. You might want to calculate the local power density when one looks at, say, a 100 W light bulb from one meter distance (with certain assumptions about size of the pupil). Convective heat transfer by the blood is probably the main mechanism to maintain temperature. Also - what fraction of invisible radiation is absorbed in the vitreous humour?